# Удалить повторяющиеся числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано число введеных чисел n. Вводим все числа в массив. Нужно убрать повторяющиеся числа.
Вот мой код,но он не проходит лимит по времени

```
n=int(input())
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
b=[]
for i in range(n):
    b.append(a[i])
    if b.count(a[i])==2:
        b.pop()
print(len(b))
print(' '.join(map(str,b)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n=int(input())
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
b=list(set(a))
```

Comment: А эта ф-ия будет быстрее моего кода?

Comment: Можно `map` сразу в `set` оборачивать.

Comment: сейчас замерю время

Comment: @Flashdim Конечно это будет быстрее, чем то добавлять элементы в список, то удалять их, да ещё искать и считать всё время элементы в списке.

Answer (score 4):

Вместо вашего

```
for i in range(n):
    b.append(a[i])
    if b.count(a[i])==2:
        b.pop()
```

используйте простое

```
for i in a:
    if i not in b:
        b.append(i)
```